# Why do i get an exception when inspecting at debug time and not at runtime / what is the best practice for mapping an enum from DB

Tags: c#, database, enums

Consider the following code snippet

```
public class Class1
{
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        Value1 = 1,
        Value2 = 2
    }
    public void TestCall()
    {
        /*some standard DB code returning an SqlDataReader...*/
        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        Item item = new Item();

        /*original code*/
        /*Database "Type" is a varchar() field containing an integer, please dont ask why :)*/
        if (rdr["Type"].GetType() == typeof(DBNull))
        {
            item.Type = TestEnum.Value1;
        }
        else if ((string)rdr["Type"] == "1")
        {
            item.Type = TestEnum.Value2;
        }
        else if ((string)rdr["Type"] == "2")
        {
            item.Type = TestEnum.Value1;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Type = TestEnum.Value1;
        }

        /*suggested code*/
        item.Type = rdr["Type"] as TestEnum? ?? TestEnum.Value1; //<- default / null value to use
    }
}
public class Item
{
    public Class1.TestEnum Type;
}
```

During code review, a colleague of mine pointed out that i could replace the cascading IFs ("original code") with a single line ("suggested code")

While the suggested code runs just fine, I get a NullReferenceException when inspecting "rdr["Type"] as TestEnum?" at debug time.

I was wondering if this is a sign of underlying problems with the suggested code, what is the prefered way of mapping a database value to an enum, and what are your thoughts on this kind of code generally speaking.

Comment: The normal way is to read the database value as an int and cast it to your enum, if they have the same underlying value.

Comment: The c# code's field is an integer (... more specifically an enum), but the database type is a varchar(); this is weird and not recommended, but out of my control (database comes from a client and must not be modified)

Comment: Then again, the method I suggested is probably what you should be doing. If you only have a couple values (like those 2), then your method is fine anyway

Comment: I don't think `string as TestEnum?` will ever succeed. IMO the "suggested code" is just wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, now what do you think about the inspection of "rdr["Type"] as TestEnum?" throwing an exception?

Comment: The debugger exception seems to be a debugger expression evaluator bug. What about "working", I doubt - the result should always be `Value1`, even if the `rdr["Type"] == "2"`, did you test that?

Comment: Ivan Stoev: you are perfectly right, i seem to always get the default value; i tested wrong and the fact is the suggested code just plain doesnt work. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I would give you credit and accept your "answer" but it looks like i cant do it on a comment?

Comment: Comments aren't answers. He has to submit it as an answer

Comment: Yeah that was my way of telling Ivan that he should post an answer for me to accept ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested code is just wrong - it will not throw exception, but will always evaluate to `TestEnum.Value1`.

Why? The reader returns the value as `object`. The `as T?` operator will evaluate to non null value *only* if the object represents a *boxed* `T` value. When the object contains `string` as in your case, or even if was a boxed `int` (the underlying type of your enum), still the operator `as TestEnum?` will evaluate to `null`, hence the expression will hit the `?? TestEnum.Value1` condition.

Shortly, don't rely on such tricks. If you want to improve that code, create a method (which can be reused from other places if needed):

```
static TestEnum ToTestEnum(object dbValue)
{
    TestEnum value;
    return Enum.TryParse(dbValue as string, out value) ? value : TestEnum.Value1;
}
```

and then change the original code like

```
item.Type = ToTestEnum(rdr["Type"]);
```